# How to force section to not go to new page in article

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, input, include, article

I have a document like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\include{sect1}
\include{sect2}
\end{document}
```

Both files sect1.tex and sect2.tex begin with `\section{...}`. The output pdf file displays *section 1* and *section 2* on two different pages even though *section 1* only occupies about 10 lines in the first page. Is there any way I can force *section 2* to start right after *section 1* one the same page?

Comment: And if those sections are so short why do you use `include` instead of put them inside the body of the document? I use `\include`with big documents such as books and the most of times with chapters not sections.

Comment: Regarding [When should I use \input vs. \include?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include), you should use `\input` instead of `\include`. `\include` inserts a `\clearpage`, which creates a pagebreak.

Comment: @Aradnix: There are some sections that are really long. The above example is just an overly simplified version of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\include{filename}` and `input{filename}` both import the file with the `filename` into the document. The most important difference of these commands in your case is, that `\include` inserts a `\clearpage` after the file (which creates a pagebreak), while `\input` only inserts the content of your file. So you should use `\input` to avoid pagebreaks.

More detailed information can be found at [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include).